# Detecting scroll in jquery and change the operations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having one jquery overlay like this.  When pageloads this will display like this. 
[image: ONLOAD]

When user clicks close or feedback button again it goes back to its position like this.
[image: POSITION]

The functionality goes like this.  Now When the user scrolls the page it should automatically goes back to its position.  Onload i am writing this jquery code to perform this operation,  onclick of close button `reset()` is called. onclick of feedback `slideme()` is called.  So my question is when users scrolls down the page this overlay should go back to position.  How to detect user scroll and perform this operation?

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    SlideMe();

    $('body').keypress(function(e)
    {
        if(e.keyCode == 27)
        {
            reset();
        }
 });

    });
    function SlideMe()
    {   
        if(document.getElementById('hdnFBStats').value == 1)
        {
            document.getElementById('hdnFBStats').value =0;
            reset();
            return false;
        }

        $lngDocWidth = ($(document).width()/3)+32;

        $('#overlay').fadeIn('fast',function(){
            $("#fb").animate({marginRight:$lngDocWidth}, 1500);         
        });

        $("#feedbackimg").css("margin-right", '100px');
        $("#feedbackimg").css("float", 'right');

        document.getElementById('hdnFBStats').value= 1;
    }

    function reset()
    {
        $("#fb").css('margin-right', '0px');
        $('#overlay').fadeOut('fast');
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will only do the scroll check if the tab is actually open.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if(document.getElementById('hdnFBStats').value == 1) {
        document.getElementById('hdnFBStats').value = 0;
        reset();
    } else {
        if($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
            SlideMe();
            document.getElementById('hdnFBStats').value = 1;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: can you try it first without the wrapping "if" statement just to verify that the scroll detection works?

Comment: @Calvin: shouldn't you check for the tab to be open INSIDE the callback. If you wrap the event binding in an if statement, it'll never get bound in the first place.

Comment: Can you please explain me how to detect the place.  I mean if user scrolls up again to the top the plugin should come out. I am new to jquery..

Comment: I've added another condition to check if the user had scrolled to the top of the page and run the SlideMe() function to slide the plugin out.

Answer (score 4):

You can use jQuery's `$(window).scroll()` event

http://api.jquery.com/scroll/